# Summarize aggregated data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table like as follows:

```
SoftwareName    Count    Country
Project         15       Canada
Visio           12       Canada
Project         10       USA
Visio           5        USA
```

How do I query it to give me a summary like...

```
SoftwareName    Canada    USA    Total
Project         15        10     25
Visio           12        5      17
```

How to do in T-SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT SoftwareName, 
  SUM( CASE Country WHEN 'Canada' THEN [Count] ELSE 0 END ) AS Canada,
  SUM( CASE Country WHEN 'USA'    THEN [Count] ELSE 0 END ) AS USA,
  SUM( [Count] ) AS Total
FROM [Table] 
GROUP BY SoftwareName;
```

Answer (score 3):

OK...Here's how to do it using PIVOT:

```
SELECT Softwarename, Canada, USA, Canada + USA As TOTAL from SoftwareDemo 
PIVOT 
    (
     SUM([Count])
     FOR Country
     IN (Canada, USA)
    ) AS x


Softwarename                                       Canada      USA         TOTAL
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Project                                            15          10          25
Visio                                              12          5           17

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Hi Marlon,  I tried this solution too, and while I don't see any improvement in terms of execution time, I think this solution is very elegant and easy to modify later on.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: With only the sample data as test load, there isn't much difference on their performance. I think this PIVOT is the *preferred* solution for this kind of data requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This is called table pivoting.  In your simple case, there are just two columns; in general, there could be 200 countries or so, in which case, the pivoting becomes rather hard.

There are many resources online describing how to do it: Google for 'pivot table sql'.

Answer (score 1):

in SQL 2005 or later there-SQL keyword "Pivot" that does this for you,
Check out the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use this Link :

[Sum of unique records - better performance than a cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165381/sum-of-unique-records-better-performance-than-a-cursor/18657739#18657739)

and i think using PIVOT Function have a best performance rater SUM() function.!