# Summarizing two conditions on the same SQL table

Tags: sql, aggregation

Given a SQL table

```
Transactions
  ID            INT
  COMPANY_ID    INT
  STATUS        INT
```

where `STATUS IN (0,1)` indicates a free transaction and `STATUS IN (2,3)` indicates a billable transaction, what simple (I hope) ANSI SQL statement will show me, per `COMPANY_ID`, the number of billable transactions, non-billable transactions, and their ratio?

A conceptual prod in the right direction is fine if not a specific statement.  My first attempts are to self-join on the table with `WHERE` clauses for the two status groups, but I'm stuck at how to get a column representing each distinct count so that I can compute the ratio.

This is conceptually very similar to [summarize-aggregated-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248990/summarize-aggregated-data) but I'm not sure how to extend that question to this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a start, I think this is along the right lines...The only thing left would be to add the ratio.

```
SELECT
    COMPANY_ID,
    NON_BILLABLE = SUM(CASE STATUS WHEN IN (0, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    BILLABLE = SUM(CASE STATUS WHEN IN (2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM TRANSACTIONS
GROUP BY COMPANY_ID
```

EDIT: for standards compliance.

```
SELECT
    COMPANY_ID,
    SUM(CASE STATUS WHEN IN (0, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NON_BILLABLE,
    SUM(CASE STATUS WHEN IN (2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BILLABLE
FROM TRANSACTIONS
GROUP BY COMPANY_ID
```

Comment: I guess SUM(CASE... END) AS BILLABLE is more standards compliant.

Comment: Thanks for this start.  I'll try it out as soon as I get in tomorrow.

Comment: My actual DB is MySQL and I had to reverse the order of "STATUS" and "WHEN" for the query to work (using the Standards Compliant one) but then it works like a charm.