# Referencing MySQL Alias of Aggregate Column

Tags: sql, mysql, alias, aggregation

Following up on my question [summarizing-two-conditions-on-the-same-sql-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786987/summarizing-two-conditions-on-the-same-sql-table), I added a RATIO column that is simply one SUM(...) column divided by a second SUM(...) column:

```
SELECT
    COMPANY_ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN (0, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NON_BILLABLE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN (2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BILLABLE
    SUM(NON_BILLABLE)/SUM(BILLABLE) AS RATIO
FROM TRANSACTIONS
GROUP BY COMPANY_ID
```

It looks nice and clean to define the RATIO like that, but also apparently [forbidden by SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error).

To get the query working, I just copied the CASE statements for NON_BILLABLE and BILLABLE.

```
SELECT
    COMPANY_ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN (0, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NON_BILLABLE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN (2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BILLABLE
    SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN (0, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN (2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RATIO
FROM TRANSACTIONS
GROUP BY COMPANY_ID
```

Is there a better, cleaner (non-redundant) way to write this query?

Comment: The problem is that you can't access the aliases (`NON_BILLABLE` and `BILLABLE`) inside the select clause of your query.  You can only reference them in the WHERE or HAVING clauses.

You *might* be able to rig it with a left join or something, but I'm not sure.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error you can't access them in WHERE clauses in standard SQL.

Comment: Ah, right!  Only table aliases are accessible in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT x.company_id,
       x.non_billable,
       x.billable,
       x.non_billable/x.billable AS RATIO
  FROM (SELECT t.company_id
              SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN (0, 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NON_BILLABLE,
              SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS IN (2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BILLABLE
         FROM TRANSACTIONS
     GROUP BY t.company_id) x
```

Comment: This isn't an exact answer but you should be able to adapt this solution to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372961/mysql-use-aliased-fields-in-aggregate-functions/76495570#76495570